# "Numpy" TypeError: data type "string" not understood

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I am a newbie trying to learn data visuallizaion using python. 
Actually, I was just trying to follow the example given by a [cookbook](https://www.google.co.jp/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQ9-Tql8TTAhWMS7wKHScaDNMQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.packtpub.com%2Fbig-data-and-business-intelligence%2Fpython-data-visualization-cookbook&usg=AFQjCNGjCjLxC_4zj4rGMbqhchOmgNau_Q&sig2=X-Whi7ng1FamajPtAvo6ng),
like:

```
import numpy
import os
os.chdir("Home/Desktop/Temporal_folder")
data = numpy.loadtxt ('ch02-data.csv', dtype= 'string', delimiter=',')
print (data)
```

but somehow it did not work out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Home/PycharmProjects/Learning/Datavisuallization.py", line 5, in <module>
    data = numpy.loadtxt ('ch02-data.csv', dtype= 'string', delimiter=',')
  File "Home/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 930, in loadtxt
    dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
TypeError: data type "string" not understood
```

this is the data I used: ["ch02-data.csv"](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/axolote/IPython_StudyNotebooks/master/python_dataviz_cookbook/ch2files/ch02-data.csv)

there were some similar issues [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25766831/numpy-structured-arrays-string-type-not-understood-when-specifying-dtype-with-a), but I am not sure I understood what the answer tried to explain. 
Also, I checked the [manual of numpy.loadtext()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), still the answer does not seem to be obvious to me... 
any suggestion? 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html

Comment: try `np.str` or just `str` : `data = numpy.loadtxt ('ch02-data.csv', dtype= numpy.str, delimiter=',')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, it works well in Python2, but it doesn't work in Python 3.x, you can try `numpy.str`

In Python 2, there's no problem:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.12.0'
>>> np.dtype('string')
dtype('S')
>>> np.dtype('str')
dtype('S')
```

In Python 3, this throw an exception:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.11.3'
>>> np.dtype('string')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: data type "string" not understood
>>> np.dtype('str')
dtype('<U')
```

you can see more details from [this issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6023).

Comment: Curious that there has been no action on this bug report (not even a comment by developers) in two years.

Comment: I'm here August/2018 with the same problem. Apparently there is no solution from python, yet. Using here Python3.6.5 Anaconda version.

Answer (score 13):

Try dtype='str' instead of dtype='string'.